# How to make the program ignore ArrayIndexOutOfBonds error?

Tags: java, error-handling, stack

I made a program in Java that converts infix expressions to posfix and calculates the posfix expression, however, certain expressions give a "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1" error message. What can I do to make the program ignore this error and still calculate the expression?

Example: 1+2*3^2/3-4*(2-1)+9 becomes 123^2*3/+421-*-9+ and results 6, 
but 1+2*3^2/3-4*(2-1)+9+ gives this error.

> Main Class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
public class Avaliador {
   private Pilha Pilha1;
   private String input;
   private String output = "";
   public Avaliador(String in) {
      input = in;
      int TamanhoPilha = input.length();
      Pilha1 = new Pilha(TamanhoPilha,false);
   }
   public String Transformar() {
      for (int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++) {
         char ch = input.charAt(j);
         switch (ch) {
            case '*': 
            case '/':
                temOperador(ch, 2); 
                break; 
            case '+':
            case '-':
               temOperador(ch, 1); 
               break;   
            case ')': 
                temParentesis(ch);
                break;
            case '(': 
               Pilha1.Inserir(ch);
               break;
            default: 
               output = output + ch; 
               break;
         }
      }
      while (!Pilha1.Vazio()) {
         output = output + Pilha1.Remover();
      }
      return output; 
   }
   public void temOperador(char opLer, int n1e) {
      while (!Pilha1.Vazio()) {
         char op = Pilha1.Remover();
         if (op == '(') {
            Pilha1.Inserir(op);
            break;
         } else {
            int n2e;
            if (op == '+' || op == '-')
            n2e = 1;
            else
            n2e = 2;
            if (n2e < n1e) { 
               Pilha1.Inserir(op);
               break;
            } 
            else output = output + op;
         }
      }
      Pilha1.Inserir(opLer);
   }
   public void temParentesis(char ch) { 
      while (!Pilha1.Vazio()) {
         char chx = Pilha1.Remover();
         if (chx == '(')
         break;
         else output = output + chx; 
      }
   }

   public int CalculoExpressao(String exp) {
       int n1,n2;
        Scanner operadores = new Scanner(exp);
        Pilha Pilha2=new Pilha(exp.length(),true);
        while (operadores.hasNext()) {
            if (operadores.hasNextInt()) {
                Pilha2.Inserir(operadores.nextInt());
            } else {
                n2=Pilha2.Remover2();
                n1=Pilha2.Remover2();
                String op = operadores.next();

                if (op.equals("+")) {
                    Pilha2.Inserir(n1 + n2);
                } else if (op.equals("-")) {
                    Pilha2.Inserir(n1 - n2);
                } else if (op.equals("*")) {
                    Pilha2.Inserir(n1 * n2);
                } else {
                    Pilha2.Inserir(n1 / n2);
                }
            }
        }
        return Pilha2.Remover2();
  }
   public static boolean checarParen(String check){
       Pilha Pilha3=new Pilha(check.length(),false);
       for(int a = 0; a < check.length(); a++)
       {
           char pal = check.charAt(a);
           if(pal == '(')
               Pilha3.Inserir(pal);
           else if(pal == ')')
           {
               if(Pilha3.Vazio())
                   return false;
               switch(pal)
               {
                   case ')':
                       if (Pilha3.Remover() != '(')
                           return false;
                       break;
                   default:
                       break;
               }
           }
       }
       if(Pilha3.Vazio())
           return true;
       return false;
   }
   public static void checarErros(String input){
       int i=0,g=0,gg=0,erros=0;
       String letrasz="",chval="0123456789()+-*/^";

       for(i=0;i<input.length();i++){
              char cju=input.charAt(i);
              if(chval.indexOf(cju)==-1){
                  letrasz+=cju+",";
              }
          }
       i=0;
       if(!letrasz.isEmpty()){
              letrasz=letrasz.substring(0,letrasz.length()-1);
              System.out.println("ERRO: A expressão possui operadores inválidos: "+letrasz+".");
              erros++;
          }
       if(!checarParen(input)){
              while(i<input.length()){
                  char cti=input.charAt(i);
                  if(cti=='('){g++;}
                  else if(cti==')'){gg++;}
                  i++;
              }
              int huh=0;
              if(g>gg){
                  huh=g-gg;
                  if(huh>1){System.out.println("ERRO: Há "+huh+" parênteses '(' sem a presença de parênteses ')' sucessores.");
                  }else{System.out.println("ERRO: Há um parênteses '(' sem a presença de um parênteses ')' sucessor.");}
              }else{
                  huh=gg-g;
                  if(huh>1){System.out.println("ERRO: Há "+huh+" parênteses ')' sem a presença de parênteses '(' antecessores.");
                  }else{System.out.println("ERRO: Há um parênteses ')' sem a presença de um parênteses '(' antecessor.");}

              }
              erros++;
          }
       if(erros>0){
           System.exit(0);
       }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
      boolean ler=true;
      String input="",output,resultado="";
      if(!ler){
          /*
          input="1+2*3^2/3-4*(2-1)+9";
          1+2*3^2/3-4*(2-1)+9
          */
          input="1+2*3^2/3-4*(2-1)+9";
      }else{
          System.out.println("Digite a expressão a ser avaliada: ");
          input=scan.nextLine();
      }
      checarErros(input);
      Avaliador Transformacao = new Avaliador(input);
      output = Transformacao.Transformar();
      for (int j = 0; j < output.length(); j++) {
          char tu = output.charAt(j);
          resultado+=tu+" ";
      }
      System.out.println("Expressão Infixa: "+input+'\n'+"Expressão Posfixa: "+output+'\n'+"Resultado: "+Transformacao.CalculoExpressao(resultado));
   }
}
```

> Stack Class:

```
public class Pilha {
    private int tammax,tammax2;
    boolean het=false;
    private char[] VetorP;
    private int[] VetorI;
    private int top;
    private int top2;
    public Pilha(int max,boolean hetz) {
     if(!hetz){
         tammax = max;
             VetorP = new char[tammax];
             top = -1;
     }else{
         tammax2 = max;
             VetorI = new int[tammax2];
             top2 = -1;
     }
    }
    public char Checar() {
        return VetorP[top];
     }
    public char Remover() {
        return VetorP[top--];
     }
    public void Inserir(char j) {
       VetorP[++top] = j;
    }
    public void Inserir(int i){
      VetorI[++top2]=i;
    }
    public int Remover2(){
        return VetorI[top2--];
    }
    public boolean Vazio() {
       return (top == -1);
    }
    public void setPilha2(){
      top2=-1;
    }
    public void getTop(){
      System.out.println(this.top);
    }
}
```

Comment: What you can do: fix your code in a way to not encounter these issues, take a look where the exceptions occur, why they occur and prevent that input from reaching a point where an exception occurs.

Comment: you shouldnt... because you are causing that....

Comment: Use a try-catch block. However I would suggest that you fix the problem instead of avoiding it.

Answer (score 0):

All kinds of strange things may happen when your program tries to access data outside the allocated space for the array in memory. You might override some important system file, or your program might execute just fine. Java is a checked language meaning that checks occur when accessing an element of the array every time. If it detects such an error it throws an exception and nothing happens(It's different than C). What you have here really is a bug. What you should do is fix the bug. I wont bother looking at your code, but you should make sure the program only accesses elements that are within the array bounds at all times.